# How to Fix "AssertionError: CUDA unavailable, invalid device 0 requested"

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to use my GPU to run the YOLOR model, and I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\yolor\detect.py", line 198, in <module>
    detect()
  File "D:\yolor\detect.py", line 41, in detect
    device = select_device(opt.device)
  File "D:\yolor\utils\torch_utils.py", line 47, in select_device
    assert torch.cuda.is_available(), 'CUDA unavailable, invalid device %s requested' % device  # check availablity
AssertionError: CUDA unavailable, invalid device 0 requested
```

When I try to check if CUDA is available with the following:

```
python3
>>import torch
>>print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

I get `False`, which explains the problem. I tried running the command

```
py -m pip install torch1.9.0+cu111 torchvision0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I get the error: `ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'torch1.9.0+cu111'`

Running `nvcc --version`, I get:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_May__3_19:41:42_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.109
Build cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29920130_0
```

Thus, I'm not really sure what the issue is, or how to fix it.

EDIT: As @Ivan pointed out, I added the == sign, but still get `False` when checking if CUDA is available.

Comment: Have you checked if your current NVidia driver supports CUDA 11.3? Also this question is pretty old already. Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 6):

Ok after 1 week of pain I have founded this solution

1- After download NVIDIA Driver:

- Go to your window and search for "NVIDIA Control Panel"
- Then at the bottom left there should be "System Information"
- Then look for "CUDA Cores"
- Mine is 384 (year my laptop is antique) (NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M)
- For CUDA Cores: 384 (corresponds to CUDA Toolkit 9.0)
- For CUDA Cores: 387 (corresponds to CUDA Toolkit 9.1)
- For other CUDA Cores you will need to do some more research yourself because I'm honestly don't know where to find this (if you are curious about where I found the one above, its on the second comments "https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4546"

2- (Optional) Download Anaconda

- This is the system I use, the choice is your
- If you are using Anaconda and have been installing and uninstall to
  fix this problem. I recommend you to clean uninstall the environment
  since in my case my file got crash because of repeated install and
  un-install
- Here is the link to show you how to do it
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcvdOuvWI-Q&t=107s"

3- After install the right CUDA toolkit for your system

- Go to "https://pytorch.org"
- Put in your system details and install the right PyTorch for your
  system
- (Optional) if you use Tensorflow as well, go here and install the
  right version for your CUDA

4- After all of that, in your Anaconda environment (or any environment you are using), type:

- import torch
- print(torch.cuda.is_available())

if return True then good job

if not: good luck on your coming week

hope it help and good luck on your journey with yolor (I'm learning it too)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put the `==` signs between the packages and the version number. According to the [PyTorch installation page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/):

```
py -m pip install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio===0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Comment: Hey @Ivan, thank you! I feel like an idiot. I just ran the command, and when executing `print(torch.cuda.is_available())`, I still get `false`. Any idea why?

Comment: Could you run `nvidia-smi` in the command line and look at the CUDA version?

Comment: Yes, I get version 11.4. For some reason, when I ran the same program in a conda environment, I get print(torch.cuda.is_available()) as True, and it works fine. Any ideas? :(

Comment: ok, which environment is the one failing with `torch.cuda.is_available()`, your regular Python cmd line, right? You might be running a different Python/Torch/etc... all together. Could you look at `pip list` and tell me if you get the correct version for PyTorch (`1.9.0+cu111`)?

Comment: When I run it, I get 
`torch 1.9.0+cu111
torchaudio 0.9.0
torchvision 0.10.0+cu111`

Comment: When you run on a conda env, do you have a different set of versions there?

Comment: Nop, same versions. Could it be some CUDA clash?

Comment: Same cudatoolkit version as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with VSCode dev containers maybe you forgot to add the GPU to the container.

This can be fixed adding to `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`

```
"runArgs": ["--gpus", "all"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall torch, torchvision, and torchaudio (if already installed). For CUDA 12.1:

```bash
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do this solution, I am here using TensorFlow 2.5.0, change it to what is suitable for you...

```
!wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/libcudnn8_8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2_amd64.deb
!dpkg -i libcudnn8_8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2_amd64.deb
!ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.*
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.5.0
```